# Remove SQL code from Rails schema file

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rails-migrations

So a while ago I was working with triggers and added a few to one of my tables for insert and update events and thus they went to my `schema.rb` but then I found a way not to use triggers and removed them from the dabatase console but their sql code obviously hadn't been deleted from the schema file, so now I have something like that in it:

```
  execute(<<-TRIGGERSQL)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.arguments_vector_update()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        new.tsv_body = to_tsvector('pg_catalog.simple', COALESCE(NEW.text, ''));
    END IF;
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        IF NEW.text <> OLD.text THEN
            new.tsv_body = to_tsvector('pg_catalog.simple', COALESCE(NEW.text, ''));
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$function$
  TRIGGERSQL
```

and I think I've deleted the migration file too -_-

I could probably add a new migration with the code to remove the trigers but it'd make the schema file even messier, so I wonder if there is another way to remove this code from the schema file ?

I am using PSQL, if it's important.

Comment: Everything is perfectly fine with this command, except that I didn't know about it haha Thank you very much. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake -T` in a Rails app will have this to say:

```
rake db:schema:dump # Create a db/schema.rb file that is portable against any DB supported by AR
```

So you can `rake db:schema:dump` to generate a fresh `db/schema.rb` file any time you need one.